# How to connect to TOR and then a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: proxy, tor

I would like to connect to TOR first, and then utilize a SOCKS proxy at the end of the connection. This way, I can access websites that have banned TOR exit nodes.

I was following the guide here: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnels/Connecting_to_Tor_before_a_proxy#Proxy_Settings_Method

However, I am confused. That guide states to change the TOR Browser's SOCKS address and port, which are set to the local TOR proxy. This isn't what I want because I still want to connect to TOR, I just want to connect to a SOCKS proxy after TOR.

So, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which program is supposed to connect through Tor and then SOCKS? You want Tor Browser to connect through Tor and then SOCKS?

Comment: Yes. Tor Browser connect to TOR and then SOCKS